# Non-thermal electron definition

Tags: electrons, terminology, definition

The question says it all, what's a non-thermal electron?

I just need a simple definition of it.

I am about to get sick of finding papers about it, but zero definition.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a hot object with a strong bias voltage on it. In a vacuum, electrons will stream off the object with individual energies that conform to a characteristic *thermal* or *blackbody* distribution.

Now imagine instead a bunch of electrons that are being emitted by, for example, a chunk of material undergoing ("beta") radioactive decay. They will *not* exhibit a thermal spectrum of energies; instead, they will exhibit a fundamentally different energy distribution that is characteristic of the particulars of the decay mode.

A physics pal (or gal) measuring the stream of electrons with a *spectroscope*, will notice right away that the spectral distribution of the electrons from the decay process does not conform to a *thermal* distribution, and will exclaim, "AHA! a *nonthermal* distribution!"

Comment: Just as I thought, thanks!